# How to scrape a site usin different rules for a spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I separated the spider from the crawler. I need to extract some data from a website using Python Scrapy using different conditions to get results. So I have the functions in first file:

```
def parse(self, response):
    xpath = '//div[@class="proinfor"]//div[@class="prolist_casinforimg"]/a/@href'
    urls = response.xpath(xpath).extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = url.replace("//", "", 1)
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                             callback=self.parse_requem)
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url),
                             callback=self.parse_obj)

def parse_requem(self, response):
    ...
    yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    parser = BaseParser(response)
    return parser.construct_item()

def parse_obj(self, response):
    parser = BaseParser(response)
    return parser.construct()
```

And the code in the BaseParser class:

```
 def parse_price(self):
    Price = response.body
    return Price

def parse_ex(self):
    exists = self.xpath('//text()').extract_first()
    return exists

def construct(self):
    item = dict()
    item['ex'] = self.parse_ex()
    return item

def construct_item(self):
    item = dict()
    item['price'] = self.parse_price()
    return item
```

As you can see, I'm trying to separate the data retrieval logic, but instead, I'm only getting the execution result from a single function.
How to separate the parsing logic for a spider?

Comment: What do you mean you only get the results from a single function?

Comment: @alexpdev I mean that I only get results from function construct_item.

Comment: You could just use item loaders for what you are doing

Comment: The most likely reason is because there is something going wrong in your BaseParser class... without more context there isn't any way for anyone to help